# Could someone please explain this (VB)

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I'm new to coding and have recently been curious about creating multiple permutations of a selection of characters. My solution had a lot of nested For Next loops which was clunky, so I searched other solutions and found the one below, however I cannot fully understand it.

```
    Dim chars() As Char = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray
Dim csize As Integer = chars.Length - 1
Dim upto As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    upto = "                                                  "

    Dim max_length As Integer = 25

    For i = 1 To max_length
        bf_recursion(0, i)
        Update()
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub bf_recursion(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal depth As Integer)
    Dim current() As Char = upto.ToCharArray()

    For i = 0 To csize
        current(index) = chars(i)
        upto = CStr(current)

        TextBox1.Text = (CStr(current))
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        Me.Refresh()
        '\\lblOutput.Text = CStr(current)

        If index <> (depth - 1) Then
            bf_recursion(index + 1, depth)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I do not understand the section where Current(Index) = Chars(i) since from my understanding it is making the Current(index) value stored in that index equal to the value in the characters, however somehow in the next line is creates a string from the Current(index) value that produces the correct result.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had to copy your code to see the result as I wasn't sure what you were trying to do, but let's get it explaining.

For the first cycle we have:

> csize = 35
>
> index = 0
>
> depth = 1

The loop is easy enough: you loop from 0 to 35 (35 included)

```
        For i = 0 To csize
```

At Index `0`of `context`, you store the character at position `i`

```
        current(index) = chars(i)
```

So when looping, this will give this result:

```
current(0) = "1" 'i = 1
current(0) = "2" 'i = 2
...
current(0) = "a" 'i = 11
current(0) = "b" 'i = 12
```

the `CStr` function changes the array `current` to a string by placing all elements one after each other:

```
        upto = CStr(current)
        Label1.Text = (CStr(current)) 
        Label1.Refresh()
        Me.Refresh()
```

Then comes the recursive part, but for the first loop, we don't need it...

```
        If index <> (depth - 1) Then
            bf_recursion(index + 1, depth)
        End If
    Next
```

---

Ok, now we finished the first cycle, let's go the the 2nd one:

> csize = 35
>
> index = 0
>
> depth = 2

What's the difference? Nothing, until we reach this code:

```
        If index <> (depth - 1) Then
            bf_recursion(index + 1, depth)
        End If
```

In the code above, index isn't the same as `depth - 1` anymore, so we go recursive, and ->important<- instead of passing `index = 0`, we pass `index + 1`! What difference does this make?

This time, we don't store our character at `current(0)` but at `current(1)`:

```
current(index) = chars(i)
```

which gives:

```
current(1) = "1" 'i = 1
current(1) = "2" 'i = 2
...
current(1) = "a" 'i = 11
current(1) = "b" 'i = 12
```

But, as the line before we did this:

```
Dim current() As Char = upto.ToCharArray()
```

`current(0)` is already filled in! Because `upto` contains the first character. That's what this line is for:

```
 upto = CStr(current)
```

---

In short:

-> You store the characters you calculated in the `upto` string.

-> Each time you enter `bf_recursion`, you recover the characters you already have

-> index is 1 larger each time, so you change the NEXT character

**One important note**

With your application, you create a very very long loop that the user can't terminate without killing the process. You might want to look into that.